# Converting an HEXEWKB to a readable geometry data in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, gis, postgis

I have a table from OSM with a column titled `way` which has values that appear to be `HEXWEKB` coded `geometry(LineString, 3857)` (I'm looking at the column type via pgAdmin).

I'm trying to understand how can i convert these into something readable so i can understand the data better (my goal is to eventually filter the data for lines only within a certain boundary).

I have tried a few queries but couldn't get this to work.

**my attempts so far:**

```
SELECT osm_id,highway,name,st_asHEXEWKB(way) as foobar
FROM planet_osm_line
WHERE highway is not null and way is not null;
```

```
SELECT osm_id,highway,name,st_geomFromEWKB(way) as foobar 
FROM planet_osm_line 
WHERE highway is not null and way is not null;
```

still getting HEXEWKB on both:

```
foobar  |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
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ST_AsText`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/ST_AsText.html) function:

```
SELECT osm_id,
       highway,
       name,
       ST_AsText(way) as foobar
FROM planet_osm_line
WHERE highway IS NOT NULL
  AND way IS NOT NULL;
```